# Cyanogenmod 13: freezes and restarts in Asus Zenfone 5

Tags: cyanogenmod, custom-roms, reboot, system-freeze, asus-zenfone-5

I have installed Cyanogenmode 13 in my Asus zenfone 5, it works perfectly for few days then started giving the following issue:

**It freezes and reboot**

I have noticed it happened randomly, sometimes while playing game, chatting, opening contact, browsing

Any suggestion.

Comment: I'd suggest you don't use that ROM, and report the problem to the ROM developer.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this happens is the bootloader being unlocked. There are random models of ZenFone 5s that are shipped by ASUS with some sort of defect in the motherboard (as they say...). If the original bootloader is replaced by an unlocked one and does not match with the bootloader originally installed on your device, the problem manifests. There are only two noted problems on those "lucky" ZenFone 5s: random freezing and disabled camera.

The only solution as of this time is to just get back into your ASUS stock ROM and re-lock your bootloader.

I know. It sucks. No one wants to help fix the problem since most users don't experience them. Just sell the phone, get a new one, and never go back to ASUS again.

I know I ain't.

Comment: Any reference of your theory?

Comment: Check out the XDA forums regarding the ZenFOne 5 bootloader problem. Lots of dev-talk there.